# How to change src image when click button in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I made 4 buttons with different background colors and I'm trying to make functionality when some of the buttons are clicked to change the image of the phone with the correct color. I've no idea how should I do it, I've tried for 5 hours and still nothing. Here are my html buttons, the logic in the methods are empty. Thank you!

```
          <button class="card" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: palegoldenrod"
                  (click)="gold()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: silver"
                  (click)="silver()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: darkslategrey"
                  (click)="midnight()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: grey"
                  (click)="spacegrey()"></button>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: even you can do all in .html: `<button (click)="img='./assets/golden.jpg'">golden</button>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<img [src]="image" />` as

HTML

```
<button class="card" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: palegoldenrod"
                  (click)="gold()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: silver"
                  (click)="silver()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: darkslategrey"
                  (click)="midnight()"></button>
          <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: grey"
                  (click)="spacegrey()"></button>

<img [src]="image" />
```

TS

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  image: any =
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTEVY7_oYz24UXM4Z15YgKhX21F-aTUBm9xR46tLgj2Ox4Mkh_w&usqp=CAU";
  gold() {
    this.image =
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTMXgK3LAKOoot-wUnzrUFPg2q4A__PbvoxKBE-iJKZOFcRKqsl&usqp=CAU";
  }
  silver() {
    this.image =
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ1gx9WC3BVjG4KYK1v8b2uBPjpughgJpYrJhIsHxbav8DPAMy-&usqp=CAU";
  }

  midnight() {
    this.image =
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR3CIz-oYt40ekYXw7CLGLfePl3B9Y5CWJW8-SZ7AZ9_WqWDSuQ&usqp=CAU";
  }

  spacegrey() {
    this.image =
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTuM7Ws8HBB1gyxb_fAmT9_k75SFH4dT2y4UcIll60HtL1F6pJQ&usqp=CAU";
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqthqc

Comment: it's working thx, what about if I've another product like Samsung S10 and want to change the  S10 image, how I can manipulate it depend of the phone, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way binding of angular, so just set [src] to image and update image url from function calls.

```
<img [src]="image">
```

Where `image` will be defined in your ts file and will be updated with image source in those specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
  <button class="card" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: palegoldenrod"
                      (click)="changeColor('palegoldenrod')"></button>
              <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: silver"
                      (click)="changeColor('silver')"></button>
              <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: darkslategrey"
                      (click)="changeColor('darkslategrey')"></button>
              <button class="card ml-1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: grey"
                      (click)="changeColor('grey')"></button>

                      <img [src]="img" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Ts:

```
  img='url/palegoldenrod.jpg';
changeColor(color){
this.img=`url/${color}.jpg`;
}
```